# Nginx - block all *.php files except index

Tags: php, nginx

I'm new to nginx.
I need to block all .php files for security reasons.
Any simple way to do it simmilar to Apache's .htaccess, as below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule !^index.php index.php [L,NC]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of usual nginx PHP handler location

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    ... # FastCGI PHP handler here
}
```

use something like

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}
location = /index.php {
    ... # FastCGI PHP handler here
}
```

Although regex matching locations (`location ~ <regex> { ... }`) are taking priority over the prefix locations (`location <URI prefix> { ... }`) on the request URI match, exact matching location (`location = <URI> { ... }`) are taking priority over both of them.

Comment: Another thing - 
<code>
location ~ \.php$ {
        rewrite ^ /index.php last;
    }
    
    location = /index.php {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
<code>
Downloads those files, how can I prevent it?

Comment: Looks like you didn't set the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` FastCGI parameter. Add the `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` directive to the FastCGI PHP handler location.